# I keep getting this R vtreat error: Error in as.data.frame.default(x) : cannot coerce class ‘"treatmentplan"’ to a data.frame

Tags: r, dataframe, r-caret

I'm trying to run a vtreat package in R.  I've partitioned the dataset into train and test data parts.  I'm trying to perform a categorical design treatment (designTreatmentC).  I keep getting the following error code:

```
Error in as.data.frame.default(x) : 
  cannot coerce class ‘"treatmentplan"’ to a data.frame
```

I'm stuck and can't find the trouble.  I've done all the things I can think of but I'm a novice.  Any help is appreciated.

I checked the plan, and dataframes.

Here's the code:

```
### MODIFY: Vtreat, need to declare xVars & name of Y var
## SAMPLE: Partition schema
set.seed(1234)
idx       <- createDataPartition(joinData$Y_AcceptedOffer,p=.7,list=F)
trainData <- joinData[idx,]
testData  <- joinData[-idx,]## MODIFY: Vtreat, need to declare xVars & name of Y var
names(trainData)
informativeFeatures <- names(trainData)[3:26]
informativeFeatures
targetFeature <- names(trainData)[27]
targetFeature
successClass <- 'Accepted'
head(joinData)
plan <- designTreatmentsC(joinData, informativeFeatures, targetFeature, successClass)

#verify class of plan, joinData, trainData, testData
class(plan)
class(joinData)
class(trainData)
class(testData)
# Apply the rules to the set
treatedTrain <- prepare(plan, trainData)
treatedTest  <- prepare(plan, testData)
```

Comment: from which line are you getting the error?

Comment: why is this tagged with r-caret when you have a problem with vtreat?